# When the ring of regular functions is a UFD?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an irreducible affine variety over $\mathbb{k}$. There is the following theorem in algebraic geometry: the algebra $\mathbb{k}[X]$ of regular functions is a UFD if and only if each irreducible submanifold of $X$ of codimension $1$ is a set $V(f)$ of zeros of some regular $f\in\mathbb{k}[X]$. I can imagine the proof and it does not seem to be complicated. However I guess that it can be derived from some results from commutative algebra (something like Krull's theorem, isn't it?). Could you give me a reference for the general theorem?

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct: Krull's theorem is at the heart of the result.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 5):

The relevant theorem in commutative algebra is:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian domain. The ring  $A$ is a UFD iff every height one prime ideal is principal.

This is Theorem 20.1, page 161, in Matsumura's [*Commutative Ring Theory*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Commutative_Ring_Theory.html?id=yJwNrABugDEC&redir_esc=y) .